# SQL Query populate a new Column with value from latest date across rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I  have a table with two columns PREVIOUS_DAY and REC_COUNT.

Now I have to populate a new column using **sql query** with SQL that supports snowflake

**Below is my input**

```
PREVIOUS_DAY    REC_COUNT
2023-08-30  2,718
2023-08-29  2,713
2023-08-28  2,724
2023-08-24  2,723
```

**Below is my expected output(FINAL_CLMN)**

```
PREVIOUS_DAY    REC_COUNT  FINAL_CLMN
2023-08-30      2,718      2718
2023-08-29      2,713      2718
2023-08-28      2,724      2718
2023-08-24      2,723      2718
```

For my latest date for ex from above input table it is 30th I have a value 2718. Now this 2718 value has to be populated across all rows as  a new columns.

**I have to retrieve latest date** corresponding REC_COUNT value and populate as new columns across rows

Can anyone help me with the SQL query in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query used and it worked

```
 SELECT PREVIOUS_DAY,FIRST_VALUE(REC_COUNT) OVER (ORDER BY PREVIOUS_DAY DESC) 
 FINAL_CLMN
 FROM <TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
t1.PREVIOUS_DAY,
t1.REC_COUNT,
t2.LATEST_REC_COUNT AS FINAL_CLMN
FROM
    your_table_name t1
JOIN (
SELECT
    MAX(PREVIOUS_DAY) AS LATEST_DATE,
    FIRST_VALUE(REC_COUNT) AS LATEST_REC_COUNT
FROM
    your_table_name
) t2
ON t1.PREVIOUS_DAY = t2.LATEST_DATE;
```